# jvmtop CPU usage >100%

Tags: performance, jvm, cpu-usage

I've been using jvmtop for a few months to monitor JVM statistics. As I've tallied the output with Jconsole, I've mostly observed similar stats in jvmtop as well.
However during a recent test execution I've observed few entries of CPU% to go above 100% (120% being the highest). Now as I believe jvmtop provides cumulative CPU usage (not like top which provides more of core-wise details), need guidance on how to interpret this entries of beyond 100% usage.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with jvmtop, but it could just be measurement error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked at [jvmtop code](https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop) and may conclude that its algorithm for computing CPU usage is completely screwed up. Let me explain.

In the simplified form, the formula looks like

```
    CPU_usage = Δ processCpuTime / ( Δ processRunTime * CPU_count)
```

The idea makes sense, but the problem is how it is actually [implemented](https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jvmtop/monitor/VMInfo.java#L366). I see at least 3 issues:

1. Process CPU time and process uptime are obtained by two independent method calls. Furthermore, those are remote calls made via RMI. This means, there can be an arbitrary long delay between obtaining those values. So, `Δ processCpuTime` and `Δ processRunTime` are computed over different time intervals, and it's not quite correct to divide one by another. When `Δ processCpuTime` is computed over a longer period than `Δ processRunTime`, the result may happen to be > 100%.
2. Process CPU time is based on [`OperatingSystemMXBean.getProcessCpuTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getProcessCpuTime()) call, while the process uptime relies on [`RuntimeMXBean.getUptime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.management/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getUptime()). The problem is, these two methods use the different clock source and the different time scale. Generally speaking, times obtained by these methods are not comparable to each other.
3. `CPU_count` is computed as [`OperatingSystemMXBean.getAvailableProcessors()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.management/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getAvailableProcessors()). However, the number of logical processors visible to the JVM is not always equal to the number of physical processors on the machine. For example, in a container `getAvailableProcessors()` may return a value based on `cpu-shares`, while in practice the JVM may use more physical cores. In this case CPU usage may again appear > 100%.

However, as far as I see, in [the latest version](https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jvmtop/monitor/VMInfo.java#L405) the final value of CPU load is artificially capped by 99%:

```
    return Math.min(99.0,
        deltaTime / (deltaUptime * osBean.getAvailableProcessors()));
```